# How to update StoreId?

Tags: foursquare

I have a lot of managed venues, each one identified by storeId.
I'm looking for the best way to update foursquare venues with this information.
StoreId is not among the venues/ID/edit parameters.
Is there another API I can use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the venueId, not the storeId, for editing venues.

Comment: To update the store ID of a venue, you can pass a storeId parameter to the venues/edit endpoint.